# NPE in reaper thread when destroying a Socket/ZContext

Tags: zeromq

Why am I getting an NPE in the reaper thread when trying to shut down my `ZContext`?

Background: I'm trying to close the ZMQ.Sockets I've created using `ZContext.createSocket(int)`. I started out trying to use `ZMQ.Context`, but I read somewhere that that's a low-level API and it was suggested to use `ZContext` instead. But now when I try and destroy the context I've created in my test runs, the operation errors out with an NPE in the reaper thread and doesn't successfully terminate the context.

I have a [ZeroMQWorker](https://github.com/reactor/reactor/blob/master/reactor-net/src/main/java/reactor/net/zmq/ZeroMQWorker.java) that sets up the `ZLoop` and is responsible for shutting down the context if it's created for each component. The tests I'm having problems with are the ones that create a new `ZContext` for the server and one for the client. They're commented out [in the tests here](https://github.com/reactor/reactor/blob/master/reactor-net/src/test/java/reactor/net/tcp/ZeroMQClientServerTests.java).

In [this test](https://github.com/reactor/reactor/blob/master/reactor-net/src/test/java/reactor/net/tcp/TcpServerTests.java#L467), the `ctx.term()` gives an NPE. Switching it to `ZContext` just hangs indefinitely for no apparent reason.

I've tried to find examples of properly shutting down contexts in the examples but frankly, I can't make heads or tails of most of them. They're not named in any way that a long-time Java programmer is familiar with and they have zero javadoc or even inline comments explaining what's happening. So far I've been struggling with just learning the basics of the API: what to do--and finding out what not to do on my own through trial and error. But this shutdown thing has me completely stumped.

**EDIT:** I made some changes and now it seems that the problem comes down to trying to terminate the context. It seems to be hanging on this operation in `Ctx.java`:

```
//  Wait till reaper thread closes all the sockets.
Command cmd = term_mailbox.recv (-1);
```